# cv::floodFill crashes when used for regions with holes

Tags: c++, opencv

The following minimum example seems to get stuck in an endless loop. It runs a few minutes to then finally crash with `std::bad_alloc` (OpenCV 3.0).

```
int main()
{
    cv::Mat img( cv::Size( 128, 128 ), CV_8UC1, cv::Scalar( 128 ) );
    cv::Mat mask( cv::Size( 130, 130 ), CV_8UC1, cv::Scalar( 0 ) );
    cv::rectangle( img, cv::Rect( 32, 32, 64, 64 ), cv::Scalar( 0 ), CV_FILLED );
    cv::rectangle( img, cv::Rect( 64, 64, 16, 16 ), cv::Scalar( 255 ), CV_FILLED ); // draw white hole in black region
    cv::floodFill( img, mask, cv::Point( 42, 42 ),
        cv::Scalar( 255 ), 0,
        cv::Scalar( 20 ), cv::Scalar( 30 ),
        cv::FLOODFILL_MASK_ONLY );
}
```

It tries to floodfill the black region.

[image]

If I remove the white hole, it works like expected. Am I calling the function with illegal parameters, or is this a bug?

Comment: I don't know if the `flags` value you pass is strictly legal -- perhaps you could play it safe and include the values for the lower bits as well (for connectivity and fill value, as mentioned in the opencv docs): `cv::floodFill (..., cv::FLOODFILL_MASK_ONLY | 4 | (1 << 8))`.

Comment: Thank you very much. This works. If you post it as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `flags` value you pass is not strictly legal -- you should include the values for the lower bits as well (for connectivity and fill value, as mentioned in the [opencv docs](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0.0/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html#gaf1f55a048f8a45bc3383586e80b1f0d0)):

```
int connectivity = 4;
int newMaskVal   = 255;
cv::floodFill (..., cv::FLOODFILL_MASK_ONLY | connectivity  | (newMaskVal << 8));
```

Comment: @Tobias Huh, that accept was quick :-) Dann schönen Freitag noch!

Comment: `cv::floodFill (..., cv::FLOODFILL_MASK_ONLY | 4 | (255 << 8))`  will be better to see the change on the mask. ( i tried to edit your answer but rejected..)

Comment: @sturkmen Yeah, looks clearer like this. I edited it accordingly.